# Pass array collection from flex to javascript function

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex, flex3

Is it possible to pass an ArrayCollection object from flex ExternalInterface.call() as a parameter to javascript function?

Flex sample code:

```
var obj:Object = new Object();
    obj.id = "Id";
    obj.name = "SomeName";
ExternalInterface.call("jsFunction",obj);
```

JavaScript code:

```
function jsFunction(flexObj){
  alert('Id::'+flexObj.id+'Name::'+flexObj.name);
}
```

I am able to get the id and name values in js as they are String objects.

My question is: can I get the arrayCollection object from Flex to JS in the similar way?

```
obj.list = arrayCollectionObj;
```

If I do in this way I am getting `null` in JavaScript. How to achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, ListCollections are actually rather complex data structures and they need to be converted to something simpler to get passed to JavaScript. Of course, if you know that all of the contents are simple, you could simply call:

```
obj.list = arrayCollectionObj.toArray();
```

Comment: if I convert and pass the array to js, how can I read the values in js?

Comment: The [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#call%28%29) say that you can just read it as an array.